# How to check if the letters in the input are in another string, but not in the same order

Tags: python, tkinter

[This is the new error that i am getting with the code. It is a screenshot with the GUI and the word file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn4ft.png)

[The image is of me typing key into the box and it doesnt show that it gives me incorrect, but afterwards it gave me incorrect. Incorrect is displayed for a short time so wasnt able to capture in screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKZa2.png)I'm trying to make a game in python where the user enters a word in a GUI (Tkinter) and the word has to be in a txt file (containing 10,000 common English words) and the letters of the input has to be in a randomly generated letter sequence.

The problem is that every time I enter a word, it says that it is a word. I figured out that the word has to be in the same order as it is in the randomly generated letter sequence otherwise it says that the word is incorrect. Can someone help me solve this issue? I don't know how to solve it :)
P.S My code is very messy and the check_in_sequence function is just a part of the checking processing i was trying out.

```
import random
from Tkinter import *


root = Tk()
Answer = Entry(root)
alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
           'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
points = 0

words = []
used = []
random_letter_sequence = ' '
results = []


def check_in_sequence():
    global random_letter_sequence
    correctletters = 0
    listanswer = list(Answer.get().lower())
    for letter in listanswer :
        if letter in random_letter_sequence:
            correctletters += 1
    if correctletters == len(listanswer):
        return True
    else:
        return False

    with open("This IS.txt") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    filecontent = [x.strip() for x in content]

def generate_sequence():
    global random_letter_sequence
        for random_letter in range(random.randint(6, 10)):
            random_letter = random.choice(alphabet)
            random_letter_sequence = random_letter_sequence + random_letter


def this_delete():
    Incorrect_Label.pack_forget()


def checking_answer():
    with open('This IS.txt') as inputfile:
        global file_contents
        file_contents = inputfile.read()
        file_contents = file_contents.strip("\\n")

    if Answer.get().lower() in random_letter_sequence and file_contents:
        global points
        print(Answer.get())
        points += 1
        PointLabel = Label(root, text=points, font='Helvetica 48')
        PointLabel.config(text=points)
        PointLabel.pack()

    else:
        global Incorrect_Label
        Incorrect_Label = Label(text='Incorrect')
        Incorrect_Label.pack() 
        Incorrect_Label.after(1500, this_delete)
    print(Answer.get())
    Answer.delete(0, END)


def enter_click(event):
    checking_answer()


generate_sequence()
check = Answer.get()

trial_dontNeedALabel = Label(text=random_letter_sequence, 
font='Helvetica 48')
Check_Button = Button(root, text='Submit', command=checking_answer)

root.bind('<Return>', enter_click)

Check_Button.pack()
Answer.pack()
trial_dontNeedALabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is not testable. You need to fix the indention before we can even test it. We have no way of knowing what goes where.

Comment: I have corrected the indents please inform me if I still have indent mistakes,

Comment: There was one small indention error. In the `generate_sequence()` function your `for` loop should be on the same column as your global statements. Other than that your program will start so it is now testable.

Comment: From what I can see it almost looks like a scrabble game. Are you trying to have the random letters be like you scrabble tiles you have to use to make a word?

Comment: I have provided an answer that should fit your needs. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes :) for a school project :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do (you didn't say if repetitions matter, in case they do, I used Counter from collection to account for that, otherwise the case is more straightforward)?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import Counter

def test_word(w):
    """return True if the word is in the list accepted_words and the word is made of letters in random_sequence (accounting for repetition). Return False otherwise. """
    return (w in accepted_words) and Counter(random_sequence)&Counter(w)==Counter(w)

#test example
accepted_words=['dog','cat', 'fish','racoon']
random_sequence='ladfaractsigo'

#print test results
print (test_word('dog')) #valid -> True
print (test_word('elephant')) #not in sequence of letters nor in accepted words
print (test_word('fish')) #good word, but not in letters
print (test_word('fada')) #in letters, but not a valid word
print (test_word('racoon'))  #all letters are valid, but 'o' is used twice -> False
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get what you meant there?

Comment: there where? I added a comment to the function. test_word return True if the word is good, False if it is not. You cannot use twice the same letter in random_sequence. accepted_words is a list of words (that you read from file in your example).

Comment: I know that I cant use twice the same letter in the random sequence and haven't used the same letter.

Comment: I meant that my function return False if you try to test a word that uses a letter more times than in your random sequence.

Comment: if you get my functions and put the accepted words in a list named `accepted_words` and the random sequence in a string `random_sequence` you can use my function to understand if the word is valid.  
The function assumes that the two variable are accessible (in same module), otherwise you can modify the function definition and pass them as argument, like

    `def test_word(w,accepted_words,random_sequence):`

The sequence of `print` at the end is just a test for the function, showing that the response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the word is in the text file and is in the random_text_string, read the whole file as a string then do

```
if word in text_file_string and word in random_text_string:
    #do stuff
```

edit after comment

loop through the input string and check if each character is in random_string like this

```
def is_input_string_good(input_string, random_string):
    for character in input_string:
        if character not in random_string:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm new to posting questions on StackOverflow, so may have messed up the indentation.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work. I think it's because I need the input to be split into letters first and then check if the letters are in the random_string. I am not sure though if that is it

Comment: the function in my answer returns true if every letter input string is in random string, otherwise it returns false so use it like that

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

After messing around with your code a bit I had to rework a few functions so I can include error checking and properly match the strings.

The major change in your code is to first check if all the letters in your answer are in the randomly generated letters available. If not it will say incorrect and `break` the sequence so it stops there. Then if all the letters match up then you can see if the word exist in the file. The reason we do it in this order is to cut back on the time spent reading a massive file to a minimum.

Also I replaced your list of letters with a build in import from the `string` library that contains all the available English letters.

```
import random
from string import ascii_letters # new import and got rid of your list of letters
from tkinter import *
from pip.utils import file_contents


root = Tk()
Answer = Entry(root)

points = 0
words = []
used = []
random_letter_sequence = ''
results = []

PointLabel = Label(root, font='Helvetica 48')

def generate_sequence():
    global random_letter_sequence
    # this for loop was indented one section to far.
    for random_letter in range(random.randint(6, 10)):
        random_letter = random.choice(ascii_letters).upper()
        random_letter_sequence += random_letter

def incorrect_submission():
    Incorrect_Label = Label(root, text='Incorrect')
    Incorrect_Label.pack() 
    Incorrect_Label.after(1500, lambda: Incorrect_Label.pack_forget())

def checking_answer():
    global points
    match_alphabet = False # used as a tracker for the letters in answer
    word_match = False # used as a tracker if answer in the file

    # Change the file path for your file
    with open('./This_IS.txt') as inputfile:
        for word in inputfile.read().split("\n"):
            file_contents = []
            file_contents.append(word)

    # first check to make sure the answer is not empty
    if Answer.get() != "":
        match_alphabet = True
        # check if all letters in the answer are in the available list.
        for letter in Answer.get().lower():
            if letter not in random_letter_sequence.lower():
                    match_alphabet = False

        # if everything above passes fine then check the file for the word in the answer
    if match_alphabet == True:
        for word in file_contents:
            if Answer.get().lower() == word.lower():
                points += 1
                PointLabel.config(text=points)
                PointLabel.pack()
                Answer.delete(0, END)
                word_match = True

    if word_match == False:
        incorrect_submission()



def enter_click(event):
    checking_answer()

generate_sequence()
check = Answer.get()

trial_dontNeedALabel = Label(text=random_letter_sequence, 
font='Helvetica 48')
Check_Button = Button(root, text='Submit', command=checking_answer)

root.bind('<Return>', enter_click)

Check_Button.pack()
Answer.pack()
trial_dontNeedALabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

keep in mind if you are trying to stay within the true nature of the scrabble formula the you will need to provide some checking that will check if a letter has already been used out of the random available letters in a word with repeat letters.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it works for some of the words, however, it doesn't for some. (very odd) For example in a sequence, 2 words could be made: say and lay. Say was correct but lay was identified as incorrect. How should I solve this problem? I used your code to check.(Both of the words are in the file, its something wrong with the random_letters i think, but i am still new to Python)

Comment: @Parth Please elaborate. I was able to make 2 separate words from the same list of letters but I did enter them one at a time. Are you trying to enter 2 words at the same time then hit the submit button?

Comment: No, i added them separately

Comment: I entered say, pressed submit, then entered lay afterward

Comment: I am able to get all results back as correct if I have a word in the file that can be made with the letters provided no matter how many words I put in.

Comment: I did run into a problem with validation. i will work on that.

Comment: @Parth I have updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: i also have a screenshot of it not working, but i am not able to put this on the comment section

Comment: @Parth If you cant add the screenshot with the image button in the editor then try adding a link to the image hosted on an image host platform.

Comment: I have added the image, but it doesn't show the incorrect label. But it is there, just not on the screenshot.

Comment: @Parth I have updated my answer. Please let me know if this helps you issue. I have added some validation to the entry field and refined the checking method.

Comment: Hi thanks for updating the answer, it is giving me an error "line 60, in checking_answer
    if check.lower() in file_contents.lower():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'"

Comment: @Parth Sorry about that. I was not getting the error you were but I have correct the problem.

Comment: It has fixed that issue, but now whenever i input a letter, it gives me a point for every input, evethough it sometimes displays incorrect, it still gives me the point

Comment: @Parth well that was interesting. Once again I had rework the function that checks the words also I removed a function that didn't even do anything in your code. `check_in_sequence()` was not even being used. Please let me know if you run into any more problems thought I believe this edit should be the last one needed. I think the way my word list file was formatted may have cause some issues. it should not be a problem now.

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work. The words are just in a text file, each word on a new line. When I tried to type in dot, it still didn't work. Sorry for the late reply. I also entered the word in different cases every time, but it still printed out incorrect. It prints out incorrect for incorrect words, but doesn't print correct for the correct words.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the issue

Comment: @Parth. Are you sure that your program is check both the answer and the list using `lower()` so that they are always comparing the strings as lower case.

Comment: Yes, there is lower() in the code comparing it as lower case

Comment: Make sure to strip all the spaces from the text as  well. There might be spaces in your word or your answer at the end of it. I can use `rstrip()`

Comment: There aren't any spaces between the answer and in the text, i cheecked